# Reasons why cordova app behave differently in Safari and iPhone6

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, safari, momentjs

I'm deploying a cordova app for iOS. When debugging I run it on Safari browser (with `ionic serve`. I also tried `ionic serve --lab`) and on the iPhone with XCode.

But both results behave differently. In the browser it shows the desired result. Neither the app on the phone nor the browser are showing errors.

What could be the reasons? Aren't they suppose to show the exact same result (I'm not only referring to the design but also the behaviours)?

Since I'm using moment.js it would show this weird behaviour. Any known issues with moment.js in combination with iPhone?

Comment: Safari on the iPhone doesn't have the mobile support for all the plug-ins, the built iOS app does.

Comment: please add more details of "what behaves differently", there could be many reasons and it is impossible to tell without more information. Always watch the Javascript console, it usually tells you what is going on, at least for Javascript code.